# recv() only reads 1 byte (implementing an FTP with winsock)

Tags: ftp, winsock, recv

I'm trying to implement a simple FTP client using winsock. I'm having problems trying to download a file. Here's the code I'm using at the moment:

```
bool FTPHandler::downloadFile(const char * remoteFilePath, const char * filePath) {
    if (!isConnected()) {
         setErrorMsg("Not connected, imposible to upload file...");
         return false;
     }   

     if (usePasiveMode) {
         this->pasivePort = makeConectionPasive();
         if (this->pasivePort == -1) {
             //error msg will be setted by makeConectionPasive()
             return false;
         }
     } else {
         setErrorMsg("Unable to upload file not in pasive mode :S");
         return false;
     }

     char * fileName = new char[500];
     getFileName(remoteFilePath,fileName);     

     // Default name and path := current directory and same name as remote.
     if (filePath == NULL) {
          filePath = fileName;
     }

     if (!setDirectory(remoteFilePath)) {
         return false;
     }



    char msg[OTHER_BUF_SIZE];
    char serverMsg[SERVER_BUF_SIZE];
    sprintf(msg,"%s%s\n",RETR_MSG,fileName);
    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

     SOCKET passSocket;
     SOCKADDR_IN passServer;

     passSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
     if (passSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
         WSACleanup();  
         sprintf(errorMsg,"Error trying to create socket (WSA error code: %d)",WSAGetLastError());
         return false;
     }

     passServer.sin_family = PF_INET;
     passServer.sin_port =   htons(this->pasivePort);
     passServer.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)gethostbyname(this->host)->h_addr);
     memset(server.sin_zero,0,8);

     int errorCode = connect(passSocket, (LPSOCKADDR) &passServer, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
     int tries = 0;
     while (errorCode == SOCKET_ERROR) {
           tries++;
           if (tries >= MAX_TRIES) {
               closesocket(passSocket);
               sprintf(errorMsg,"Error trying to create socket");
               WSACleanup();
               return false;
           }
     }

     char * buffer = (char *) malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
     ofstream f(filePath);

     Sleep(WAIT_TIME);
     while (int readBytes = ***recv(passSocket, buffer, CHUNK_SIZE, 0)***>0) {
           buffer[readBytes] = '\0';
           f.write(buffer,readBytes);
     }
     f.close();

     Sleep(WAIT_TIME);
     recv(sock, serverMsg, OTHER_BUF_SIZE, 0);
     if (!startWith(serverMsg, FILE_STATUS_OKEY_CODE)) {
         sprintf(errorMsg,"Bad response: %s",serverMsg);
         return false;
     }

     return true;
}
```

That last recv() returns 1 byte several times, and then the method ends and the file that should be around 1Kb is just 23 bytes.

Why isn't recv reading the hole file?

Comment: What are the 23 bytes?  Also, I'm not at all sure about issuing the RETR before opening the data connection to the server.  Isn't the server supposed to send some ACK message on the data port after it is successully opened, ie. the client should listen for the ACK before issuing RETR etc?

Comment: The 23 bytes seems like rubish. If i try to download a small file (like 50bytes) then it only read 1 byte. I don't think the server is supposed to send any ACK message.

Comment: OK, maybe you're right - some time since I did this stuff.  Next, what does 'buffer[readBytes] = '\0';' do?  It seems to put a null on the end of the data which is then not written to the file anyway, so it's redundant.  Next, debugging - what have you done so far?  If you break on the f.write, what's the value of readBytes and what is in the buffer?

Comment: Yeah, the 'buffer[readBytes] = '\0 is there cause when i did the debug, i needed to see the buffer :-P The buffer always stores just 1 random byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are all kinds of logic holes and incorrect/missing error handling in this code.  You really need to clean up this code in general.

You are passing the wrong `sizeof()` value to `connect()`, and not handling an error correctly if `connect()` fails (your retry loop is useless).  You need to use `sizeof(sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof(passServer)` instead of `sizeof(sockaddr)`.  You are also not initializing `passServer` correctly.

You are not checking `recv()` for errors.  And in the off-chance that `recv()` actually read `CHUCK_SIZE` number of bytes then you have a buffer overflow that will corrupt memory when you write the null byte into the buffer (which you do not need to do) because you are writing it past the boundaries of the buffer.

If `connect()` fails, or `recv()` fails with any error other than a server-side initiated disconnect, you are not telling the server to abort the transfer.

Once you tell the server to go into Passive mode, you need to connect to the IP/Port (not just the Port) that the server tells you, before you then send your `RETR` command.

Don't forget to send the server a `TYPE` command so it knows what format to send the file bytes in, such as `TYPE A` for ASCII text and `TYPE I` for binary data.  If you try to transfer a file in the wrong format, you can corrupt the data.  FTP's default `TYPE` is ASCII, not Binary.

And lastly, since you clearly do not seem to know how to program sockets effectively, I suggest you use the FTP portions of the WinInet library instead of WinSock directly, such as the [`FtpGetFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157.aspx) function.  Let WinInet handle the details of transferring FTP files for you.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I forgot to accept the answer when I had to. I have to say that the point of all of this was trying to get a better understanding of how FTP works, not downloading a file =)